# Android: Fragments using a method from MainActivity not defined in the interface?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I'm having some design pattern confusion/issues. I have a Fragment that needs to call methods from the MainActivity that's not defined in the Fragment's interface. An obvious solution would be just to cast the attached Activity as a MainActivity, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of the interface?

This is my MainActivity has methods a(), b(), and c():

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AInterface, CInterface {

      @Override 
      public void a(){//method A body}

      public void b(){//method b body} //no Override

      @Override 
      public void c(){//method C body}
}
```

This is my Fragment Class and NEEDS a(), b() and c().
Method c() is from another Fragment's interface:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment{
    private AInterface mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = (AInterface)activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);

        mActivity.a();
        (MainActivity) mActivity.b(); //is it ok to just call it like this?
        (MainActivity) mActivity.c(); //is it ok to just call it like this?
        return v;
    }

     public interface AInterface{
         public void a();
     }
}
```

Is this the correct way of calling those methods? Thanks.

Comment: How do you create your fragments? If you inflate and create them manually and you manually add them to the `FragmentManager`, you can pass in the callback to the fragment when you `new` it up. If you automatically inject it, the below solution of having a call back on the `onAttach()` is a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do it like this, since your are creating a tight coupling between your Activity and your fragment.

A better approach would be to use a callback.

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface Interface1{
        public void b();
    }

    public interface Interface2 extends Interface1{
        public void a();
    }

    public interface Interface3 extends Interface1{
        public void c();
    }

    Interface2 mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (Interface2 ) activity;
        } 
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+ " must implement ItemselectedCallback");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach(){
        mCallback = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    //somewhere 
    mCallback.a();

}
```

Your activity would then implement the callback interface and handle the callbacks.

```
public class TaskActivity extends Activity implements MenuFragment.Inferface2, MenuFragment.Interface3{
    public void a() {
        //do something
    }
    public void b() {
        //do something
    }  
    public void c() {
        //do something
    } 
}
```

Comment: what are your thoughts on having 2 different interfaces from 2 diff fragments, but they share common methods? For example both my fragments need method b(), so should I put method b() in both interfaces?

Comment: ty for updated answer! I just have one more question, Let's say I have a method in my MainActivity that's been there since the beginning, like `calculateXYZ()`. Suddenly I need a Fragment that needs to call this method. Should I add that method to my Fragment interface? It just seems weird to add `@Override` to a method that been there from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that and it will work, **BUT** you will also need to be careful when the casting failed (solveable with instanceof)
It will also make your SomeFragment class coupled to your MainActivity class which is not a best practice.
I think the better and safer approach is to use interface.

Comment: should I add ALL methods in I need in my Fragment to my AInterface? even methods technically from another interface like method c()?